# Is my ER Diagram correct according this business rules?

Tags: database-design, schema, erd

Tiny Hospital keeps information on patients and hospital rooms. The system assigns each patient a patient ID number. In addition, the patient’s last name, first name, date of birth, and date of admission are recorded. Also, every patient is seen by a Physician who develops a treatment plan for the patient. Each Physician may see many patients. Some patients are resident patients (they spend at least one night in the hospital) and others are outpatients (they are treated and released). A Check back date is recorded for all out patients, and a Date of discharge is recorded for all resident patients. Resident patients are assigned to a room. Each room is identified by a room number.   The system also stores the room type (private or semiprivate), and room fee. Over time, each room will have many resident patients that stay in it. Each resident patient will stay in only one room. Every room must have had a patient, and every resident patient must have a room.

[image: ERD]

Comment: No, it doesn't look right. Surely, a treatment plan cannot be an attribute of a physician. Also, a patient might be admitted multiple times, which in your model is not allowed. You may want to check out [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291425/how-to-model-a-table-in-a-relational-database-where-all-attributes-are-foreign-k).

Comment: Thank you very much mustaccio,I will check it out!